# Reuse a windows 10/11 license on a VM when throwing away the previous VM

Tags: windows

Can a Windows 10 or 11 license be reused in a new VM when throwing away the old VM? I've probably read somewhere that when activating a Windows instance the license gets associated to the CPU serial number or other serial (e.g. network card). Is it enough to disassociate the license from the old VM before throwing it away? What if the VM gets corrupted and disassociating the license from the VM is not possible?